# Vim - Bind a key to a bash command

Tags: vim

In VIM, is there a way to bind a key to a shell command? For example when F3 is pressed `git commit -a -m "test"` should be executed.

Comment: Note: there are vim extenstions like [vim-fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) that provides shortcuts for git commans.

Comment: Despite the existence of plugins, there is something to be said for learning how to do it yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `map <F3> :!sh -xc 'git commit -a -m "test"'`.

Comment: Why bother going through `sh` rather than just `:!git commit -am "test"`?

Comment: @Kevin: I'm sorry, but I don't know the difference. I just used to do it this way. AFAIK they have no difference, But I'm going to wait for better answer. Thanks to your question.

Comment: You should probably use `nmap`, otherwise pressing `<F3>` in insert mode will insert the right hand side as text. Consider `nnoremap`, so that plugins can't override your binding. Also you can use `<silent>`, as in `nnoremap <silent> <F3> :git commit -am 'test'` if you just want to run the command without echoing it. See `:he map`.

Comment: nnoremap does not protect bindings from being overridden. nnoremap means that the RHS will use the default meanings of vim keys and not user redefined ones: `nmap / :echo "foo"<CR>/` will do an infinte recursion echoing foo, `nnoremap / :echo "foo"<CR>/` will echo foo once and start a search

Answer (score 9):

```
map <F3> :!git commit -a -m "test" <enter>
```

Building on other answers, this removes the redundant invocation of `sh` and launches the command without having to press enter.

I was looking for this and couldn't find, also I cannot comment, so I made it an answer.